# Embedded Scala REPL inherits parent classpath

Tags: scala

As asked in [this thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-tools-nsc-Interpreter-and-classpath-td2548176.html) on the Scala mailing list, how can I create an embedded Scala REPL that inherits the classpath of the parent program? Suppose the parent Scala program is launched using `scala -cp <classpath> ...`; can `<classpath>` be accessed as a string and used to initialize the embedded REPL? (The *Java* classpath, available via `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`, appears to differ from the Scala classpath.)

Alternatively, perhaps the embedded Scala REPL can inherit or construct its ClassLoader from the parent process (Michael Dürig's ScalaDays 2010 talk might be relevant). Is this the recommended approach?

Comment: I've never before heard of an Scala interpreter. Where can I get it?

Comment: By interpreter I mean the Scala REPL. It comes with the Scala compiler. It's what you get when you execute the `scala` executable from the command line. This question is about embedding a REPL within a running Scala program.

Comment: I have edited your answer to reflect that you mean REPL.

Comment: @ziggystar The words interpreter and REPL are somewhat interchangeable. For example: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2097

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm trying to do the same thing, and I just found a way my out by [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=discover+classpath+current+classloader):

```
lazy val urls = java.lang.Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader match {
  case cl: java.net.URLClassLoader => cl.getURLs.toList
  case _ => error("classloader is not a URLClassLoader")
}
lazy val classpath = urls map {_.toString}
```

The above code gets you the classpath in current context.

```
settings.classpath.value = classpath.distinct.mkString(java.io.File.pathSeparator)
```

Put that into your `settings.classpath` and you should be able to fire up dispatch or whatever library you need.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. The workaround that I had settled on was to use the Java classpath environment variable (i.e. `$CLASSPATH`) instead of the Scala classpath. The Java classpath is inherited by the embedded interpreter, and then the "usejavacp" option works.

Answer (score 2):

set the `usejavacp` property to true:

```
val settings = new scala.tools.nsc.Settings
settings.usejavacp.value = true
```

Comment: This technique does not seem to add the _Scala_ classpath to the newly created interpreter. As documented in `scala.tools.nsc.StandardScalaSettings.scala`, this option only includes `java.class.path` in classpath resolution.

Comment: Have a look at https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/wiki/Classpath and the related source code at http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/svn-repos/scala/scala-msil/trunk/src/compiler/scala/tools/util/PathResolver.scala
These describe the current class path handling in quite some detail.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this information. Is there a way to access the instance of scala.tools.util.PathResolver in the currently executing program? If so, I can reuse its Settings object for the embedded interpreter I'm creating.

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be an easy way to access the "Scala classpath" from within a running Scala program (in contrast, the "Java classpath" is available through the `java.class.path` system property). One would like to access, e.g., the field `Calculated.userClasspath` in the instance of `scala.tools.PathResolver`, but the latter does not seem accessible. Perhaps the easiest work-around is to modify the `scala` launch script to store the `-classpath` parameter string in an environment variable.

Assuming the desired Scala classpath can be determined, it can be passed to the embedded Scala interpreter via:
`settings.classpath.value = ...`

**Update**: although the Scala classpath string may not be directly attainable from the Scala runtime, @Eugene points out that it can be extracted from the context classloader. Thanks.