# scala.tools.nsc.IMain within Play 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, classpath, read-eval-print-loop

I googled a lot and am totally stuck now. I know, that there are similar questions but please read to the end. I have tried all proposed solutions and none did work.

I am trying to use the `IMain` class from `scala.tools.nsc` within a Play 2.1 project (Using Scala 2.10.0).

**Controller Code**

This is the code, where I try to use the `IMain` in a Websocket. This is only for testing.

```
object Scala extends Controller {
  def session = WebSocket.using[String] { request =>
    val interpreter = new IMain() 
    val (out,channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[String]
    val in = Iteratee.foreach[String]{ code =>
      interpreter.interpret(code) match {
        case Results.Error =>      channel.push("error")
        case Results.Incomplete => channel.push("incomplete")
        case Results.Success =>    channel.push("success")
      }      
    } 
    (in,out)
  }
}
```

As soon as something gets sent over the Websocket the following error gets logged by play:

```
Failed to initialize compiler: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
```

**Build.scala**

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  val appName         = "escalator"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.10.0"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(    
  )
}
```

**What I have tried so far**

All this didn't work:

- I have included `fork := true` in the `Build.scala`
- A `Settings` object with:

  - `embeddedDefaults[MyType]`
  - `usejavacp.value = true`
- The soultion proposed as answer to Question [Embedded Scala REPL inherits parent classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121567/embedded-scala-repl-inherits-parent-classpath)

I dont know what to do now.

Comment: have you tried something simpler like (new scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain()).interpret("val x = 1") match ...

Comment: @Iraklis yes. I put that in the initialization code in Global.scala. Same error message.

Comment: You may also want to look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23925201/3686016) regarding this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that  sbt doesnt add scala-library to the class path.
The following workaround works.
First create a folder lib in the top project directory(the parent of app,conf etc) and copy there the scala-library.jar

Then you can use the following code to host an interpreter :

```
      val settings = new Settings
      settings.bootclasspath.value +=scala.tools.util.PathResolver.Environment.javaBootClassPath + File.pathSeparator + "lib/scala-library.jar"
      val in = new IMain(settings){
            override protected def parentClassLoader = settings.getClass.getClassLoader()
      }
     val res = in.interpret("val x = 1")
```

The above creates the bootclasspath by adding to the java class the scala library. It's not a problem with play framework it comes from the sbt. The same problem occures for any scala project when it runs with sbt. Tested with a simple project. When it runs from eclipse its works fine.

**EDIT**: [Link to sample project demonstrating the above.](http://ubuntuone.com/6W5bCYLsBLwiHROGpPgGM0)`

Comment: doesnt work for me. now the error message changed to `scala.annotation.Annotation` from `scala.runtime`... but still the same issue.

Comment: you might havent copy the correct scala-library.jar. if you want i cant send you the porject i used.

Comment: i used the 2.10.0 scala-library. that would be awesome. you can find my mail address in my profile.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort! i'll have a look into it now. :)

Comment: ok. i just ran the app and got the exact same error when i opened `/echo´ . so it has to have something todo with the outer setup... I dont know what else to try. :(

Comment: whats is your operating system? maybe try the following instead of ":" write File.pathSeperator

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29829/discussion-between-iraklis-and-martin-ring)

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if the reflect jar is missing. Try adding this too in appDependencies.

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.0"
```

Comment: unfortunately, that didnt help... :(