# Set scala REPL classpath

Tags: scala, classpath, read-eval-print-loop

I have set an environment variable for the classpath:

```
~/spark-0.8.0-incubating-bin-hadoop1 >echo $CP
:/home/sboesch/spark-0.8.0-incubating-bin-hadoop1/conf:/home/sboesch/spark-0.8.0-incubating-bin-hadoop1/assembly/target/scala-2.9.3/spark-
```

However that is not visible for System.getProperty in the repl:

```
~/spark-0.8.0-incubating-bin-hadoop1 >scala -classpath $CP 
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_23).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> System.getProperty("java.class.path")                                                                                                                              
res0: java.lang.String = .
```

Comment: It seems that the scala classpath differs from the java classpath : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121567/embedded-scala-repl-inherits-parent-classpath . Perhaps scala -cp sets only the scala-classpath.

Comment: Any ideas how to set the internal java cp ?  e.g. -J-cp $JAVA_CP