# scala: FOO cannot be cast to FOO

Tags: java, scala, reflection, compiler-construction, casting

In Scala, I am incredibly confused by this fairly tautological error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: FOO cannot be cast to FOO
```

I would expect that someone can always be cast to its own type.

---

### Context

I am trying to run the following wrapper around the scala compiler, located at http://code.google.com/p/rooscaloo/source/browse/trunk/rooscaloo/src/org/darevay/rooscaloo/Interpreter.scala Unfortunately, Scala is saying `ResultHolder cannot be cast to ResultHolder` when I do the following:

```
import org.darevay.rooscaloo._
println(new Interpreter().eval("2"))
```

I thought `println` was supposed to accept `Any`. What should be going on is that Interpreter.eval returns a `ResultHolder` type, such that `ResultHolder.value` would be equal to `2`.

Additionally, trying to print `.value` doesn't work with the error:

```
(fragment of Test.scala):3: error: value value is not a member of Any                                                                                                                                                 
println(new Interpreter().eval("2").value)
```

---

### More details

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException                                                                                                                                                                           
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.darevay.rooscaloo.ResultHolder cannot be cast to org.darevay.rooscaloo.ResultHolder
        at binder0$.set(<script>:1)
        at binder0.set(<script>)
        ... 24 more (unsure how to print them)
```

Though I am a Scala newbie, perhaps the internal mechanism `binder` of the `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter` package is trying to do something weird.

I'm invoking the script as `scala Test.scala`.

---

### Question

My question is: What is the cause of this error message, what is the real issue, and how does one get working sample code for scala.tools.nsc.[interpreter]? Thanks.

Comment: I've seen this kind of message normally when someone ends up loading the same class with different class-loaders. Not exactly a solution, but something you might want to investigate further.

Comment: @Sanjay: Thank you. Unfortunately I am not that familiar with the inner workings of Java; what does that mean? I understand that a .class file is the compiled version of a file, containing JVM bytecode, and that a ClassLoader is something that loads the class according to some policy (I am guessing there is some kind of default filesystem classpath-based ClassLoader?). I am confused about your comment however because I do not understand where a ClassLoader "lives", and what normally would cause multiple ClassLoaders to implicitly be used in the same program. Thank you.

Comment: The Scala "interpreter" first compiles the code, then loads the class into JVM.

Comment: Also, this code seems to be quite old. I tried it with Scala 2.7.7, 2.8.1 and trunk and got various errors, all related to `org.darevay` not being in the classpath. I didn't get your error at all, so if you could provide more details into how to reproduce (Scala version, what steps did you take), it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issue, and I've converted my code to use [`IMain#mostRecentVar`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/IMain.html#mostRecentVar%3aString) introduced in Scala 2.9. Here's from [`CompilerMatcher`](https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb/blob/master/integration/src/test/scala/CompilerMatcher.scala) I wrote:

```
  val main = new IMain(s)
  main.compileSources(files.map(toSourceFile(_)): _*)
  code map { c => main.interpret(c) match {
    case IR.Error => error("Error interpreting %s" format (c))
    case _ => 
  }}
  val recent = main.mostRecentVar
  val holder = main.valueOfTerm(recent)
  if (holder != Some(expected))
    println("actual: " + holder.map(_.toString).getOrElse{"None"})
```