# Compile and execute Scala code at runtime

Tags: scala, interpreter, dsl

Is is possible to compile and execute scala code as a string at runtime either in Scala or in Java?

My idea is to build a DSL using Scala then let Java programmers use the DSL inside Java.

I heard that the class scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter can do something like that, but when I imported it inside my scala file, I got "object tools is not a member of package scala."

So could anybody give me a hint?

Comment: You need to add **scala-compiler.jar** to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am coding in an Eclipse environment by the way. So do I need to download scala-compiler.jar then add it to the build path? Where can I find scala-compiler.jar?

Comment: In addition to tenshi answer, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala/6082750#6082750) should help you with examples of Interpreter usage.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, that's correct. Grab your version of scala here: http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads.  Then unzip it and look in the **lib** folder. I also recommend you to look at [sbt](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt). I heard that it's eclipse integration improved lately.

Answer (score 17):

In 2.10.0 we expose Scala reflection API, which among everything else includes a runtime compilation facility. More details can be found here: [Generating a class from string and instantiating it in Scala 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122939/generating-a-class-from-string-and-instantiating-it-in-scala-2-10/12123609#12123609).

Answer (score 8):

I recommend you [twitter-util](http://twitter.github.com/util/)'s [Eval](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-eval/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Eval.scala)

Answer (score 2):

For scala3 this can be now achieved with `dotty`:

- https://index.scala-lang.org/lampepfl/dotty
- https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty
- https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/internals/overall-structure.html

The sbt dependency is e.g. `"org.scala-lang" %% "scala3-compiler" % "3.1.3"`