# Manual AST generation in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10, toolbox

In a response to:
[Generating a class from string and instantiating it in Scala 2.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122939/generating-a-class-from-string-and-instantiating-it-in-scala-2-10?rq=1)

@EugeneBurmako states:
"The example uses manual AST assembly, but it's possible to write a function that parses a string, finds out unbound identifiers, looks up values for them in some mapping and then creates corresponding free terms. There's no such function in Scala 2.10.0 though."

What API calls might help one find unbound identifiers?

Comment: `What's the best way?` is not a valid question on SO. Describe your problem and what you want to achieve or count the seconds until your question is closed.

Comment: Edited in the light of the above comment.