# Use Scala Quasiquotes to generate a class which inherits from a known class

Tags: scala, scala-quasiquotes

This is easier to explain in code. I want to do something like:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()

val universe: scala.reflect.runtime.universe.type = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import universe._

class A { def a = "hello A" }

val c = toolbox.compile(q"""class C(x: Int) extends A { def r = x }""")
```

Note how the dynamically generated class `C` inherits from a class `A` that's known/already-compiled.

1. Is there some way to use a toolbox that knows about `A`?
2. How do I use a dynamically generated class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example. The "pasted" class is loaded by the REPL's class loader, so you can supply it explicitly. You can also use `tb.eval`.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import reflect.runtime._,universe._,tools.reflect.ToolBox
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._
import tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> :pa -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package p { class Parent(val i: Int) }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> val tb = runtimeMirror($intp.classLoader).mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@5e316c74

scala> tb.compile(tb.parse("""case class Child(j: Int) extends p.Parent(42) ; val c = Child(17) ; c.j"""))()
res0: Any = 17

scala> val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@59a67c3a

scala> tb.compile(tb.parse("""case class Child(j: Int) extends p.Parent(42) ; val c = Child(17) ; c.j"""))()
res1: Any = 17
```

There is surely an example in the docs somewhere or on this site.

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to use `Child` outside the toolbox? e.g. pass it to a method back in normal Scala-land.

Comment: There is no normal Scalaland, only the multiverse. You can return an arbitrary value from tb.eval, an instance of `Child`, `classOf[Child]`, etc. `tb.define` gives you a symbol for a top-level class that you can pass back to toolbox (normally classes are local classes). http://stackoverflow.com/q/12122939/1296806 similarly http://stackoverflow.com/q/12122939/1296806

Comment: Apparently this code doesn't work outside the repl as `$intp` is a magic repl-ony value. Is there an equivalent that I can compile?

Comment: That was just to show that mirrors have a defining class loader. `currentMirror` does the work of picking the class loader.

Comment: Problem is I can't get it to work outside the REPL. Using `currentMirror` I get "not found: type Parent".

Comment: Ah, figured out the problem! I was trying to use a top-level classname without the package. For some reason unknown to me Scala doesn't like that.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it and it just worked. And I just tried omitting the p in p.Parent and it still works. But I'm glad it works for you, too.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I posted a related followup question here if you care to gander: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053796/performance-and-caching-of-generated-code-in-scala