# How to get the full class name of a dynamically created class in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, runtime-compilation, scala-compiler

I have a situation where I have to get the fully qualified name of a class I generate dynamically in Scala.  Here's what I have so far.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

val generatedClass = "class Foo { def addOne(i: Int) = i + 1 }"
tb.compile(tb.parse(generatedClass))

val fooClass:String = ???
```

Clearly this is just a toy example, but I just don't know how to get the fully qualified name of Foo.  I tried sticking a package declaration into the code but that threw an error when calling `tb.compile`.

Does anyone know how to get the fully qualified class name or (even better) to specify the package that Foo gets compiled under?

Thanks

EDIT

After using the solution proposed I was able to get the class name.  However, the next step is the register this class to take some actions later.  Specifically I'm trying to make use of the [UDTRegistration](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/UDTRegistration.scala) within Apache Spark to handle my own custom [UserDefinedType](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/UserDefinedType.scala)s.  This strategy works fine when I manually create all the types, however, I want to use them to extend other types I may not know about.

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122939/generating-a-class-from-string-and-instantiating-it-in-scala-2-10) it seems like what I'm trying to do might not be possible using code compiled at runtime using reflection.  Maybe a better solution is to use Scala macros, but I'm very new to that area.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `define` instead of `compile` to generate new class and get its package

```
val cls = tb.define(tb.parse(generatedClass).asInstanceOf[universe.ImplDef])
println(cls.fullName) //__wrapper$1$d1de39015284494799acd2875643f78e.Foo
```

Comment: This is perfect, but I realized that my question was insufficient.  I've edited the question to reflect my new needs.