# Creation of a case class at runtime from a map

Tags: java, scala

I have a map containing the fields of a case class I would to create.
I don't want to only instantiate the class, I want to create it from scratch and use it at run time.
The class I want to create will only contains fields (no methods).

One of my first was to interpret code at runtime that would return this new class from string interpretation.
We can do something like this with toolBox:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
 val cm = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val tb = cm.mkToolBox()
  val myClass = tb.eval(tb.parse("class C(val a:Int, val b:Int); scala.reflect.classTag[C].runtimeClass"))
```

I found the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122939/generating-a-class-from-string-and-instantiating-it-in-scala-2-10/12123609#12123609).
But I don't know what to do after.
I have the myClass object which seems to be a java.lang.Class.
Since the code line:

```
println(myClass.getClass.getName)
```

returns:

```
java.lang.Class
```

What should I do after?
Would I manage to do what I want with this?
If no what are the others possibility.

Comment: How would other classes be able to use an instance of a dynamically created class?

Comment: I don't know much about the subject so I can't answer.