# Create complex data from Strings in Scala

Tags: scala

I have defined a number of case classes such as

```
  abstract class Foo
  case class Bar(s: String) extends Foo
  case class Baz(f: Foo) extends Foo
  case class FooBar(l: Foo, r:Foo)
```

that allow me to create complex data, e.g.,

```
  val x = FooBar(Bar("1"), Baz(Bar("2")))
```

I want to read these type of data from a string, such as

```
  val x = what_to_do_here?("FooBar(Bar("1"), Baz(Bar("2")))")
```

<strike>In a dynamic language I would just call eval.</strike>
(Edit: I really do not want to call something like eval in scala)

The solution I came up with in scala was to write a parser. Is there a simpler way to do that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that there's a construct that's symmetric with `toString`. I'm pretty sure there isn't one.

Since what you're discussing is a classic serialization/deserialization scenario, you may want to look into a serialization library (one possibility that comes to mind is [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/), which with I've had considerable success, but there are certainly alternatives). Either that, or I've completely missed your usage scenario :-)

Comment: It is indeed a deserialization szenario. However, I cannot control the  output of the serialization (because I do not own the code) so using a library isn't an option. I think I'll have to write a little parser

Comment: You could, as you suggest, mock it by integrating the Scala REPL, but I wouldn't recommend it. A simple parser would be much simpler to implement and less error-prone (assuming a reasonable set of classes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [scala interpreter to write your own eval function](http://blog.darevay.com/2009/01/remedial-scala-interpreting-scala-from-scala/). Since the interpreter is actually a compiler, I don't think this will be very fast.