# Can I execute a scala code file as a part of my code?

Tags: scala, dsl

I woud like my application to execute external scripts written in a Scala-based DSL i've developed. That's why I need something like this to work:

```
...
val a = evaluate("~/myextcode.scala")
...
```

myextcode.scala:

```
return 123
```

Can I reach some thing like this in Scala?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala. Daniel Spiewak says use JRuby!

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with `Eval` from twitter util. Check its Scaladocs [here](http://twitter.github.com/util/util-eval/target/site/doc/main/api/com/twitter/util/Eval$.html).

Comment: Has this been ported to 2.9.x? Last time I checked I was unable to find binaries or compile the code...

Comment: I haven't checked it for 2.9.x. So don't know.