# Scala code as data

Tags: scala, functional-programming, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“eval” in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala)

Dr. Subramaniam in his presentation http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LH75sJAR0hc at min 30 when he starts talking about functional style in Scala he gives this example

```
class Car {
  def turn(direction: String) = {
    println("turning " + direction)
  }
}

val car = new car
car turn "left"
```

and then he says that the last line could be read from a data file and evaluated. So, data becomes code, code becomes data.

How does Scala supports this? Does it have an `eval` function?

Comment: Ever heard of a hashtable? Put your string commands in a hashtable with corresponding actions (functions) as values.

Comment: +Marcin, that's an implementation detail. You're still writing an interpreter. And there are many ways to do that.

Comment: @DonStewart I think it's an abuse of language to describe every function that accepts strings or tokens to trigger behaviour as an interpreter. In any case, it's not a mere detail that it is very easy to implement this sort of thing in a language with first-class functions.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much every language supports an `eval` function (even strongly, statically typed languages like Haskell). Many language runtimes built for languages that are primarily implemented via bytecode interpretation (such as Lisp-like languages, Erlang or Java) support the ability to insert new (byte)code at runtime.

*Once you can insert new code dynamically, you can write eval*.

Scala is an example of such a language, where [the JVM is available at runtime](http://blog.darevay.com/2009/01/remedial-scala-interpreting-scala-from-scala/).

Even in language implementations without speciﬁc support for full meta-programming, or even dynamic linking, there are often ways to dynamically generate code under programmer control, either via reﬂection mechanisms or code generation support libraries (such as LLVM).

Beyond just a simple one-stage eval, more generally, languages that support multi-stage computation allow for generation of programs from one stage to the next, for arbitrary numbers of stages, making it possible to safely, arbitrarily nest evals.

**Background reading**

- McCarthy, John, [History of LISP](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/history/lisp.ps), SIGPLAN Not. 1978. -- introduces `eval`

Comment: Could you give an example of how to evaluate code dynamically in Scala.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/package.html

Comment: Haskell? eval? How? Am I going crasy, doctor? :)

Comment: `eval :: Typeable a => String -> Maybe a`