# How to invoke the Scala compiler programmatically?

Tags: scala, scala-compiler

I want my Scala code to take a Scala class as input, compile and execute that class. How can I programmatically invoke a Scala compiler? I will be using the latest Scala version, i.e. 2.10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### ToolBox

I think the proper way of invoking the Scala compiler is doing it via Reflection API documented in [Overview](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html). Specifically, [Tree Creation via parse on ToolBoxes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree_creation_via__on_es) section in 'Symbols, Trees, and Types' talks about parsing `String` into `Tree` using `ToolBox`. You can then invoke `eval()` etc.

### scala.tools.nsc.Global

But as Shyamendra Solanki wrote, in reality you can drive scalac's `Global` to get more done. I've written [CompilerMatcher](https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb/blob/b2f29c3e211deb752750c8311691e47b3f536081/integration/src/test/scala/CompilerMatcher.scala) so I can compile generated code with sample code to do integration tests for example.

### scala.tools.ncs.IMain

You can invoke the REPL `IMain` to evaluate the code (this is also available in the above `CompilerMatcher` if you want something that works with Scala 2.10):

```
  val main = new IMain(s) {
    def lastReq = prevRequestList.last
  }
  main.compileSources(files.map(toSourceFile(_)): _*)
  code map { c => main.interpret(c) match {
    case IR.Error => sys.error("Error interpreting %s" format (c))
    case _ => 
  }}
  val holder = allCatch opt {
    main.lastReq.lineRep.call("$result")
  }
```

This was demonstrated in [Embedding the Scala Interpreter](https://web.archive.org/web/20111020090514/http://suereth.blogspot.com/2009/04/embedding-scala-interpreter.html) post by Josh Suereth back in 2009.

Answer (score 4):

The class to be compiled and run (in file test.scala)

```
class Test {

   println ("Hello World!")

}
```

// compileAndRun.scala (in same directory)

```
import scala.tools.nsc._
import java.io._

val g = new Global(new Settings()) 

val run = new g.Run  

run.compile(List("test.scala"))  // invoke compiler. it creates Test.class.

val classLoader = new java.net.URLClassLoader(
    Array(new File(".").toURI.toURL),  // Using current directory.
    this.getClass.getClassLoader)

val clazz = classLoader.loadClass("Test") // load class 

clazz.newInstance  // create an instance, which will print Hello World.
```

Comment: when I try to run this I get the following error:

error: error while loading Object, Missing dependency 'object scala in compiler mirror', required by /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class)

running Scala 2.13.1 and Java 1.8.0_231

do you know how to resolve this?