# How to execute "sbt compile" from a Scala application without resorting to executing the sbt shell script?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Scala application and I want to call SBT from my Scala application, but I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to do this?

So for the moment I am just going to call `sbt` from the shell by starting the command from within my Scala program, but in the ideal case, I would like to just call a function to start SBT to compile and produce my JAR.

Comment: This can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322543/how-to-invoke-the-scala-compiler-programmatically