# Compile Scala code to .class file, in Java

Tags: java, scala

In a project I need to replace a Java compilation task with a Scala compilation task. The first step I need to take is to find an equivalent for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Is there anything like this in Scala? A brief Google search gave no interesting results.

What I need is a library that allow me to take a file in the form of a list of lines or also a file on the HD and compile it.

I don't simply need to evaluate it but I must be able to get a compiled .class file from it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322543/how-to-invoke-the-scala-compiler-programmatically It's about compiling Scala from Scala code, but since it's all in the JVM, this might be translated easily.

Comment: Is there any example or tutorial in Java?

Answer (score -1):

You can invoke `scalac` with [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). Otherwise, you'll just need to translate Scala code from the question linked by @mastov, it's pretty trivial:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
import scala.tools.nsc.*;

Global g = new Global(new Settings());

Global.Run run = new g.Run();

// assumes you have a Java list of file names
run.compile(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(fileNames).toList);
```

Comment: I believe there is a typo here and that it should be: `import scala.collection.JavaConversions;` (i.e. minus the "s" on collections).