# How to compile and run scala code at runtime from a java program?

Tags: java, scala, java-compiler-api, scala-compiler

I already have a program that uses JavaCompiler api for compiling Java code at runtime. Can I use the same compiler for scala code? If not, what is the best way to compile scala code in a Java program?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following answer, and in it, also the answer linked by @mastov. You may, however, be able to use the new process handling capabilities in Java 9 instead of ProcessBuilder.

[Compile Scala code to .class file, in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289182/compile-scala-code-to-class-file-in-jav)

On Java 9 Process API:

https://www.javaworld.com/article/3176874/java-language/java-9s-other-new-enhancements-part-3.html

Comment: I tried the method in the link provided, and I am running into this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Global$gen$.mkBlock(Lscala/collection/immutable/List;)Lscala/reflect/internal/Trees$Tree;
Any leads on this?