# Scala: Store list of methods to execute in text file

Tags: scala

I have an Scala application that contains several methods.  I want to be able to store a list of a subset of those methods in a text file somewhere.  When my application execute, I want it to read that text file execute the methods I have specified there.  Any idea how to do that?

I know I can create list of functions in Scala (List[Int => Int], or something similar)that contains the method names, and then just iterate over that list.  The problem is how do I dynamically create that list from the text file and get Scala to recognize I am trying to give it a method name, not just a plain text string.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a list of predefined possible methods, or do you want to be able to have any function in your list?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should use reflection.  I'm not familiar enough with scala reflection, but here's a good link: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html.  Take a look at the section titled Accessing and Invoking Members of Runtime Types

Comment: Ideally it could be any function.  I could create a list of possible methods, which does give me an idea of how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the method calls in proper Scala syntax in a text file, you can add a small class wrapper around them (see example below). The (in the app) call the compiler as shown in [How to invoke the Scala compiler programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322543/how-to-invoke-the-scala-compiler-programmatically) and have the object compiled, then execute `ThingsToDoWhenAppStarts.methodToCallFromApp()`

```
package com.myco.compcall
import scala.tools.nsc._
import java.io._
object MyApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fn = "/MyTextFile.txt"
    val f = new File(getClass.getResource(fn).toURI)
    val s = new Settings()
    s.embeddedDefaults[ThingsToDoWhenAppStarts]
    s.outdir.value = "target/scala-2.11/classes"
    val compiler = new Global(s)
    val testFiles = List(f.getAbsolutePath)
    val runner = new compiler.Run()
    runner.compile(testFiles)
    val ftfCls = Class.forName("com.myco.compcall.FromTextFile")
    val ftf = ftfCls.newInstance().asInstanceOf[ThingsToDoWhenAppStarts]
    ftf.methodToCallFromApp()
  }
  def method1(): Unit = {
    println("Method1")
  }
  def method2(s: String): Unit = {
    println(s"Method2: $s")
  }
}
abstract class ThingsToDoWhenAppStarts {
  def methodToCallFromApp(): Unit
}
// ---------- ---------- ---------- //
// src/main/resources/MyTextFile.txt
package com.myco.compcall
class FromTextFile extends ThingsToDoWhenAppStarts {
    def methodToCallFromApp(): Unit = {
        MyApp.method1() // a call to a method defined in the app
        MyApp.method2("an argument") // a call to a method defined in the app
    }
}
```