# invoking scala compile using java

Tags: scala

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322543/how-to-invoke-the-scala-compiler-programmatically) about invoking scala in scala but I want to do it in java.

How does this line translate to java?

```
val run = new g.Run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `g: G` and that `new G` is the same as `new G()` (no implicit parameters) then I guess something like:

```
final G.Run run = g.new Run();
```

(I expect path dependent types to degenerate into [nested classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class))?