# What is the difference between IMain and Global.Run in Scala?

Tags: scala, interpreter, scala-compiler

I would like to interpret Scala code from within Scala. I found two approaches on the web:

1. [IMain](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.x/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain) e.g. [here](https://github.com/mattpap/IScala/blob/master/src/main/scala/Interpreter.scala)
2. [Global.Run](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.x/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.Global%24Run) e.g. [here](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-eval/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Eval.scala)

Is there a difference in performance? Also, I would like to get the results of the evaluation.

Comment: I'm always curious why there's so much interest in this sort of thing. What leads you to want to do this?

Comment: Oh, I am just hacking on a IPython notebook like thing for Scala. I know there are already some projects doing this but I want to try it on my own and do a few things differently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala