# Evaluate String expression as code in Scala

Tags: scala

how to evaluate/execute String expression as a code in Scala

Example

```
var data = "1+2"
prinln(eval(data))

>>> 3
```

So, in the above expression 1+2 is String, as there are double quotes around it. But on evaluation, it executed as arithmetical expression and answer is 3

Similarly, I have some dynamic scala code which is in the form of String, so I want to execute that.

I tried to search but didn't get anything. Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142979/dynamic-code-evaluation-in-scala#39143272

Comment: The "already has an answer" text should indicate the correct answer, lest anyone assume the green check is still optimal. Does anyone assume that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16883871/1296806