# how to convert string into runnable code in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i want to create case class dynamically and for that i wrote program but not able to define case class as program return String type instead of defining class.

eg. case class + " " + $class_name " (" + $col_list + ")"

expected: defined class abc

Comment: Dynamic code generation is not very common in Scala and especially in a distributed environment like spark might quite hard to get correct. What is the problem you try to solve originally?

Comment: I wonder if one can create an instance of the repl and can pass strings into it though.

Comment: possible dupulicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142979/dynamic-code-evaluation-in-scala#39143272 it looks like there is a IMain interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: you need to be 100% sure that the code you are generating compiles.

You can do this:

```
val yourPath = ...\\somePath.scala 
new PrintWriter(yourPath) {

  write(s"case class $class_name($col_list)")
  close()
}
```

This way you create a scala class parsing Strings. If the class generates wrong it wont compile, so you need to be sure what you are generating.