# How to instantiate Spark ML object from JSON?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark-ml

Creating Spark ML object we just need to know:

- The type of model
- The parameters for the model

I am just brainstorming a way to pass this information using `json` and instantiate a Spark ML object from it.

For example, with this json

```
{
    "model": RandomForestClassifier,
    "numTrees": 10,
    "featuresCol": "binaryFeatures"
}
```

It will instantiate a Random Forest model.

```
val rf = new RandomForestClassifier().setNumTrees(10).setFeaturesCol("binaryFeatures")
```

It is fairly straightforward to write a custom `json` serializer/deserializer by my own. Scala's `pattern match` seems good use case to dynamically instantiate an object from the name in string. However, when the object gets more complex **(i.e. supporting pipeline)**, it is hard to maintain the custom serializer.

Is there any existing implementation for this? If not, what should the `json` structure look like?

Comment: do you have to use scala? I only mention because python's reflection capabilities are much easier imo

Comment: I guess I can use pyspark-submit too. Do you have some cool resources about python's reflection?

Comment: python is inherently reflected as its a pure scripting language instead of a compiled language, so I'm not sure how to go into depth there.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala is a nice starting point to start using reflection in Scala. I'm stuck with old versions of spark/scala, so it might be a LOT easier with more recent versions