# I have a StructType schema. I want to store it in a separate file in the same format and read it in my Spark program from that file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema

I have the below schema,  `val schema = new StructType( Array( StructField("Age",IntegerType,true), StructField("Name",StringType,true), ) )`

I want to keep it in a separate file in the same format and use it in my Spark program. I have seen that I can create a json format schema in a file for the same and use it in my program. But is there a way to use the same structtype format in a file and then read it?

Just to note, my schema file can contain multiple schemas like

```
val schema1=...
val schema2=...
val schema3=...
```

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark, python provides [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function. You can use this function to parse the expression to get `StructType`.

```
>>> s=eval('StructType([StructField("name",StringType())])')
>>> s
StructType(List(StructField(name,StringType,true)))
```

But I'm not sure if we can achieve the same thing in scala. You can try with some options mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala).

You can use simple DDL format to specify the schema instead of JSON.

```
val schema = DataType.fromDDL("Age int, name string")

val structTypeSchema = schema.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

You can mention your schema in a file as shown below:

```
schema1 = c1 string, c2 int
schema2 = c3 int
```

You can read this file and create schema variables as shown below:

```
val prop = new Properties()
prop.load(new FileReader("/file/path"))

val schema1 = DataType.fromDDL(prop.getProperty("schema1"))
val schema2 = DataType.fromDDL(prop.getProperty("schema2"))
```

If you want you can use [this](https://github.com/lightbend/config) library to parse configs instead using Properties class.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My schema file can have multiple schemas. Like schema1 = ..., schema2 = ... as I want to keep all the schemas in the same file so that I can find them in one place. I have edited the question as well.

Comment: Thanks again. But instead of DDL format, can I use the StructType and StructField format in the file itself, the same way I have put the schema in the question. 
val schema = new StructType( Array( StructField("Age",IntegerType,true), StructField("Name",StringType,true), ) ) and then read that using prop.getProperty()

Comment: But once you read that from file you will have schema as string not as StructType. As I mentioned python has `eval` to parse schema expression but need to check if we have such functions in scala. Explore the link which I added in my answer.

Comment: Is there an option to handle multiline schema as I have huge number of columns in the schema .I want to keep it in multilines so that it's easily readable. for example, 
schema1 = c1 string, 
                   c2 int

schema2 = c3 int

Comment: use \ at the end of the line.